# Navigating between pages

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new in this area and have such situation that i have two pages:

```
MainActivity.axml
SecondActivity.axml
```

I have a button in MainActivity called BtnOther, in this button i want to navigate to SecondActivity. In SecondActivity i have button btnBackToExisting1stPage which i want to go back to MainActivity. Generally it works but:

1. After either BtnOther or android back arrow is clicked application is going to minimize on emulator and not staying in front. Why is that and how to avoid that?
2. I would like when pressing either BtnOther or back arrow to go back from SecondActivity to MainActivity BUT to open exact MainActivity state as was before. For instance if i would have text edit field on MainActivity and put some text before going to SecondActivity and then when going back from SecondActivity i want to see exact same form state of MainActivity instead of creating new as seem to be in my current code.

My current code:

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
 {
      protected  override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
          base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
          Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
          Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
          // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
          SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

          var btnOther = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Other);
          btnOther.Click += BtnOther_Click;
      }

      private void BtnOther_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
         StartActivity(nextActivity);
         Finish();
      }
}

public class SecondActivity : Activity
{
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
          base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
          // Create your application here
          SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Second);

          var btnBackToExisting1stPage = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BackToExisting1stPage);

          btnBackToExisting1stPage.Click += OnBackPressed;
      }

      private void OnBackPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          OnBackPressed();
      }

      public override void OnBackPressed()
      {
          Toast.MakeText(this, "Back button Pressed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
          base.OnBackPressed();         
          Finish();
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `startActivityForResult` https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: don't call finish when starting the next activity. just finish or clear it with flags later on

Comment: You want me to answer this?

Answer (score 2):

While starting second activity from button click, you are calling "**finish()**" which destroys the MainActivity and creates SecondActivity. Just remove/comment the "finish()" call. You will have the retained instance as it is in MainActivity even while clicking back button.

Comment: and startActivityForResult what for ?

Comment: startActivityForResult can be used if you want to start SecondActivity, where it to do some processing and return a result to MainActivity.

Comment: refering to your answer "while clicking back button" - you mean back button on android device? - you mean it will return to the same instance as was before? If that's correct how to do the same but from programmable button from code?

Comment: You can mimic the android hardware back button by calling onBackPressed() programatically, wherever you need it in the activity. Additionally if you need to do something before finishing, you can override onBackPressed and write your stuff and then call super.onBackPressed()